# Can I "populate" properties from other tables in a query?

Tags: soql, query

I'm trying to do this

```
List<User> users = [SELECT
                    Username, 
                    UserRole.Name,
                    FROM User where UserRoleId != null];

System.debug(users);
```

And my resulting object doesn't contain any names from UserRole.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that the users which are being fetched have any roles associated?

Comment: If you're querying Customer Community Users, they don't have a Role.

Comment: @RajivBhatt Yes, my users have roles. I've edited the query to ignore all that don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to execute below query from query editor in developer console. It is giving UserRole.Name value for me. Add the condition userroleId != null to ensure that it is returning only users with role.

> `SELECT Username,UserRole.Name FROM User where userroleId != null`

If you are trying to use user role name in apex, you can try as below,

```
for(user u:[SELECT Username,UserRole.Name FROM User where userroleId != null]){
   system.debug('User Role Name -->'+u.UserROle.Name);   
}
```

Comment: I ran that and I'm getting back `User` objects where the `UserRoleId`, `Username,` and `Id` are populated.

Comment: You are looking for user role name right?. I have updated answer to show that

Comment: Oh, I see. I was expecting it to put the name of the role in the `User` object, for some reason.